# Validate DateTime in Symfony Form

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have just started building REST API in Symfony3 (first project in Symfony ever) with FosRest bundle and I have problem with DateTime object validation in Form.

Ok, so I have this Doctrine Entity (simplified for clarity):

```
class Campaign
{
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdDate;

public function __construct()
{
    if ($this->getCreatedDate() == null) {
        $this->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime('now'));
    }
}

/*
getters and setters
*/
}
```

I also have following form build for it

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('createdDate', DateTimeType::class)
    ;
}
```

and postAction in Controller

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Campaign();
    $form = $this->createForm(CampaignType::class, $entity, array("method" => $request->getMethod()));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $entity;
    }

    return FOSView::create(array('errors' => $form->getErrors()), Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

I have two problems with it:

First, the major one - DateTime object is bind to form, but validation says that *"This value is not valid"*. I don't know why this happens - I read about setting locale params that is corresponding to timezone but it didn't work.

Second, less important (should I make second topic for this?)  -
If I don't send createdDate param in json CreatedDate param in form is set as null.
I found workaround with sending

```
  {"createdDate":""}
```

And modyfing form to

```
$builder
        ->add('createdDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'empty_data' => new \DateTime('now')
        ])
```

but sending empty param just looks so ugly. Is there any way to do this in a proper way?

Comment: Why not simple use the __construct() method of your Compaign entity like this: __construct(){ $this->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime("now"));}  and remove the field createdDate from the form ?

Comment: how your post data looks like ?
The correct datetime post data should look like:
`form[created][date][day]:18
form[created][date][month]:8
form[created][date][year]:2016
form[created][time][hour]:11
form[created][time][minute]:19`

But you don't have to add this field on the form if you set date in constructor

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem. I was simply surprised with DateTimeObject not going trough dateTime form validation.

Thanks both of you.